# Should I create a redirect to my HTTPS website

Tags: vue.js, heroku, redirect, https

I created a simple [Vue](https://vuejs.org/) web application that is hosted by Heroku on a custom domain. Heroku automatically provides SSL certificates and my website works as intended on:
`https://www.example.com``

The intended behaviour is as follows (if secure/feasible):

```
example.com -> https://www.example.com
http://example.com -> https://www.example.com
http://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com
```

however the current situation is:

```
example.com -> http//www.example.com
http://example.com -> site cannot be reached
http://www.example.com -> http://www.example.com
```

I read quite some articles online but I am not sure whether a redirect introduces potential security issues. Additionally there are a few limitations [flagged](https://help.heroku.com/NH44MODG/my-root-domain-isn-t-working-what-s-wrong) by Heroku. My Webhost is `https://www.domein-registreren.nl/` and allows redirects through their web interface.

EDIT: I used [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/) to fix the issue for me. However, I am wondering if there are other ways to accomplish this.